# How to cancel a request call on feathers-client?

Tags: feathersjs

I followed this link to setup a feathers service class to serve a websocket service by `primus` (https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html). And clients are using `feathers-client` to use these methods. However, there are some cases to cancel a request from the client side. Is there a way to cancel it?

Comment: what do you mean by "cancel a request from the client side" ?

Comment: it means if the server takes a long to execute the request. Can client cancel this request through feather-client?

Comment: This sounds like `timeouts`. If it is then yes. You just need to set them in the options of your preferred transport layer (socket, primus, http request)

Comment: It does sound like `timeout`. But we have a requirement that users can cancel a request from UI. I have setup a timeout value of 30 seconds. Before timeout, users should be able to cancel the request manually. That means I need to implement a cancel operation through feather-client.

Comment: That sounds complicated. Why not do it so that you will only send a request to the server if the user will not cancel on a given time, like your 30 secs. That way, your logic stays in the client side. Also think about it , if you are sending request to an outside api, you can't cancel request once they are sent. You only get timeout's if you wait too long.

Comment: My problem is that the server usually takes a long time(probably 1 or 2 minutes) to complete the request. I want to provide a way for users to cancel it instead of waiting for 2 minutes. If it is hard to do it on the client side, whether I can do it on the server side? For example, users send a cancel request to feathers service which will be used to cancel the previous request.

Comment: I can't think of a way to cancel a request to a feathers service. Once it is sent, the server is the one handling it. You can only create another service to revert all the changes done by the previous service. Sorry, can't help you with it. I can only advice to divide that service into smaller services so that you don't need to change a lot of stuff once its cancelled.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway.